# how to remove &nbsp by javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code

```html
<select name="category_id">
    <option value="0">All Categories</option>
    <option value="57">Books</option>
    <option value="63">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Aboriginal Authors & Studies</option>
    <option value="64">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsnbsp;Animals & Birds</option>
    <option value="117">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Green Guide</option>
    <option value="65">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Atlases</option>
    <option value="86">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Regional Atlases</option>
    <option value="87">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Road Atlases</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the `&nbsp;`s?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without replacing the malformed `&nbsp;` you can replace the innerHTML of each node

```
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option')
for (index = 0; index < options.length; ++index) {
  options[index].innerHTML = options[index].innerHTML.replace(/\&nbsp;/g, '');
}
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/2h6hqc0g/

Comment: Bad idea, since string `&nbsp;` can appear in the HTML while not being an HTML entity, for example it can appear in attributes (in `data-` or any other actually). It would be better to do `innerText.replace(/ /g, '');` The character in `/ /` is `U+00A0 NBSP`.

Comment: @Danon This removed the actual spacing that I had in the text, so the answer by Varon/Rayon is the correct one.

Comment: @MuhammadAli StackOverflow replaced my nbsp with regular space. `replace(/\xa0/g, '')` should work

Answer (score 6):

> Use ***String.prototype.replace()***, replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. If the pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.

```js
var str = "All Categories Books   Aboriginal Authors & Studies  &nbsp;Animals & Birds        Green Guide   Atlases        Regional Atlases        Road Atlases";
var op = str.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
document.getElementById('op').textContent = op;
```

```html
<div id="op"></div>
```

Comment: this is  really helpful